# MassTransit Saga(s) and Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core, microservices, masstransit-courier

Is there guidance available on how best to organize microservices using MassTransit Saga's and Kubernetes?

Should the state machine be setup on it's own? No other activities in the microservice other than the state machine? And is it safe to run multiple copies of the state machine, one each it their own kubernetes POD?

Alternatively is running the state machine and consumers all together in one microservice ok? And is it safe to run multiple copies, consumers and state machine(s), as kubernetes replicas?